# Cant get interactive chart with data.json to work?

Tags: javascript, charts, dataset

New to coding keep getting error:
`"Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got ']'"`

`data.json`:

```json
[
 {
   "date": 1,
   "state": "Ala",
   "app": " ChristianMingle"
 },
 {
   "date": 2,
   "state": "Alask",
   "app": " Match"
 },
 {
   "date": 3,
   "state": "Ariz",
   "app": "Tinder"
 },
 {
   "date": 4,
   "state": "Arkan",
   "app": "Farmers Only"
 },
 {
   "date": 5,
   "state": "Cali",
   "app": "Tinder"
 },
 {
   "date": 6,
   "state": "Co",
   "app": "Tinder"
 },
 {
   "date": 7,
   "state": "Con",
   "app": "Tinder"
 },
 {
   "date": 8,
   "state": "Del",
   "app": "Tinder"
 },
 {
   "date": 9,
   "state": "Fl",
   "app": "Tinder"
 },{
   "date": 10,
   "state": "Ga",
   "app": "Tinder"
 },{
   "date": 11,
   "state": "Hi",
   "app": "Tinder"
 },
 {
   "date": 12,
   "state": "Ida",
   "app": "Tinder"
 },
];
```

[image: HTML]
[image: End of html]

Comment: Please don't post screencaps of code, provide code as text

Answer (score -1):

The JSON is a very strict language. You should not use after the last element `,`, and should not use `;` after the array.
After the `,` mark, the JSON are waiting for a new list elem (that can be `STRING`, `NUMBER`, `NULL`, `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `OBJECT`(that begins with`{`),`ARRAY`(that begins with `[`),), but get a `]`.